# Pronouncing back to back 's' words

Tags: pronunciation

I am having trouble pronouncing back to back 's' words.

Suppose I want to say:

> **He loves English songs.**

How should I say it without giving a pause between **english** and **song** ?

Is it

> He loves Engli**sho**ngs.
>
> or
>
> He loves Engli**so**ngs.

I hope you understand what I am trying to say here.

Comment: In very rapid speech the two sounds might coalesce (to something midway between them - closer in sound to your first than your second, but not quite there), but normally, even when speaking quickly, I glide from one sibilant to the other with no pause in between.

Comment: I cannot glide from one sibilant to other that smoothly, I feel awkward and end up giving one awkward pause. So, when talking, I should prefer I first one as it sounds closely to the first words ?

Comment: One trick that I have heard of is to interpose another vowel between the two words, for example, an "a". "English songs" then becomes "English-a-songs." Your task then, with practise, is to make that "a" as unnoticeable as possible. This at least gives you something to work on, rather than requiring you to create the seemingly impossible out of nothing.

Comment: @Mick: Nah, that's gonna make you sound like a caricature of an old Italian organ grinder.

Comment: @Spectra: Practice going from *shhhhh* to *sssss*  and back to *shhhhh* by sliding the tongue forward to touch the area behind the front teeth and back again. Go slowly at first and then increase your speed. The hacks some commenters want you to try here are a cure that is worse than the disease. Then try word combos like "fish songs" and "base shift" (again, slowly at first) and then increase your speed until "English songs" trips off your tongue.

Comment: Why do you think people would even do this? I don't... I'd always pronounce them both.

Comment: Really you need a phonetician to answer the question, because native speakers are an unreliable source about native speech (we tend to firmly believe we speak more precisely and correctly in casual conversation than we actually do).  As someone said at WordReference: "in fast speech you could say *spani shpeakers* and no one would understand anything but *Spanish speakers*. The **actual phonetics of recorded speech almost never corresponds to what people think they've said**." ( https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pronunciation-sh-before-s-eg-spanish-speaker.3200315/ )

Comment: @rjpond: It's true that native speakers do not grind out phonemes one at a time like sausages, and that some get severely reduced. Nevertheless, when we speak quickly often the mere attempt at uttering, say, the *sh* in "Spanish speakers" substitutes in the ear for the full phoneme. I recall a French woman trying to correct my pronunciation of *blancmange*. I was dropping the *c* completely, and insisting I was doing it right because it sounded right to me. "Of course," she told me, "but you *sound* like you're leaving it out." Meaning she wanted to hear that vestigial phoneme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither way. The /ʃ/ (sh) in English and the /s/ in songs are two different sounds. They are not interchangeable and any effort to eliminate one of them is going to make you sound drunk or like you have a speech impediment, particularly the first one you suggest. The only acceptable way is Engli**shs**ongs

Rather than speed up, sometimes it is helpful to slow down. Get accuracy first, then practise speed because if you can't say it slowly then you certainly won't be able to do it rapidly.